# Android JSON web service issue

Tags: android, json, web-services

I need to include JSON in my android app,
I have followed some tutorials and have the app reading a test from twitter

```
package com.or.jsonswitch;

import  ***

public class JsonTestMySwitchActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.d("msg", "app started 1");

    String readResponse = readResponse(); //crea un string llenado por lo que devuelve la funcion()

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readResponse);
        Log.d("msg", "number of entries::"+jsonArray.length());
        Log.d("msg", "response::"+jsonArray);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //donde va el stacktrace?
    }

}

public String readResponse() { //autogenera como private!, cambio a public!

    Log.d("msg" , "entra a buscar");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/vogella.json");
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://myswitch.merged.stage.orchard.net.au/LifftService.svc/JSON/CoverageSearchByLatLong/-33.881393,151.214534");

    //httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    //httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "json");


    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet); //que es?
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine(); //que es?
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) { //200?
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); //que es?
            InputStream content = entity.getContent(); //que es?
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content)); //que es?
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("msg" , "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("msg", "client protocol exception:"+e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("msg", "client protocol exception:"+e);
    }       
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Note that it works when fetching the JSON data from Twitter:

```
//HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/vogella.json");
```

but appears blank when fetching from my desired server:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://myswitch.merged.stage.orchard.net.au/LifftService.svc/JSON/CoverageSearchByLatLong/-33.881393,151.214534");
```

I have no error messages when it returns blank,

do I have to set headers specifying it is JSON? How?

```
//httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "json");
```

Comment: I'd start debugging this by doing a cURL on your URL and see the differences between the Android response and the cURL response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem,

is because the response is not an array, is a dictionary, and I was making the response an array,

im not in my coding computer so cant post code right now, but that was basically the problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below code will give you  JSONObject then loop take jsonarray from this jsonobject and loop through the results...Hope it will help you

```
JSONObject jobject = null;

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myswitch.merged.stage.orchard.net.au/LifftService.svc/JSON/CoverageSearchByLatLong/-33.881393,151.214534");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

      //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        try{

            jobject = new JSONObject(result);            
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: hi, the link seems to work for me, but that wasnt the problem, please  read my own answer, thanks man